# What are the required files for windows phone app package?

Tags: windows-phone

I am trying to make a package for my windows phone app, I need to know what are the required  files by windows store to validate my package?

Answer (score 0):

You may find all what you need thanks to the Windows Certificate Kit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/jj657973.aspx)